# How can I check that GCC is installed correctly?

Tags: gcc

I have installed GCC with apt-get.

How can I check that it is installed correctly and which version?

Comment: #include <stdio.h> int main() { printf("Hello, world!\n"); return 0;
} Then, open a terminal and change directory to where you created the file, and run this: gcc test.c -o test
./test

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just type on the commandline:

```
gcc -v
```

(give you both version and programs invoked by this compiler)

```
gcc --version
```

(give you the gcc version)

Answer (score 15):

Or you can also create a *Hello World* to see if it links and compiles properly. Create a file named `test.c` with the following in it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then, open a terminal and change directory to where you created the file, and run this:

```
gcc test.c -o test
./test
```

If it prints `Hello, world!` on the terminal, it's properly installed and ready to compile.

Answer (score 3):

```
which gcc
```

will enable you to know whether gcc is installed in your /usr/bin folder or not